# Zipping lists of unequal size

Tags: python, data-structures

I have two lists

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [9,10]
```

I want to combine (zip) these two lists into one list `c` such that

```
c = [(1,9), (2,10), (3, )]
```

Is there any function in standard library in Python to do this?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Normally, you use [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) for this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = [9, 10]
>>> for i in itertools.zip_longest(a, b): print(i)
... 
(1, 9)
(2, 10)
(3, None)
```

But `zip_longest` pads the shorter iterable with `None`s (or whatever value you pass as the [`fillvalue=`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=fillvalue#itertools.zip_longest) parameter). If that's not what you want then you can use a [comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter out the `None`s:

```
>>> for i in (tuple(p for p in pair if p is not None) 
...           for pair in itertools.zip_longest(a, b)):
...     print(i)
... 
(1, 9)
(2, 10)
(3,)
```

but note that if either of the iterables has `None` values, this will filter them out too. If you don't want that, define your own object for `fillvalue=` and filter that instead of `None`:

```
sentinel = object()

def zip_longest_no_fill(a, b):
    for i in itertools.zip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=sentinel):
        yield tuple(x for x in i if x is not sentinel)

list(zip_longest_no_fill(a, b))  # [(1, 9), (2, 10), (3,)]
```

Answer (score 9):

Another way is `map`:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [9, 10]
c = map(None, a, b)
```

Although that will too contain `(3, None)` instead of `(3,)`. To do that, here's a fun line:

```
c = (tuple(y for y in x if y is not None) for x in map(None, a, b))
```

Comment: `x if None not in x else tuple(y for y in x if y is not None)`. The `x if None not in x` is redundant here, as the `else` takes care of it. In the worst case, the `else` would return an empty tuple. Also, if there's a `None` in any tuple, the `if` would kill that tuple and pass it on to the `else`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Thanks. But now it's not quite as fun :D

Comment: Works nicely in Python 2.7, but not in 3.5. For 3.5 use `itertools.zip_longest`.

Answer (score 3):

It's not too hard to just write the explicit Python to do the desired operation:

```
def izip_short(a, b):
    ia = iter(a)
    ib = iter(b)
    for x in ia:
        try:
            y = next(ib)
            yield (x, y)
        except StopIteration:
            yield (x,)
            break
    for x in ia:
        yield (x,)
    for y in ib:
        yield (None, y)

a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [9, 10]
list(izip_short(a, b))
list(izip_short(b, a))
```

I wasn't sure how you would want to handle the `b` sequence being longer than the `a` sequence, so I just stuff in a `None` for the first value in the tuple in that case.

Get an explicit iterator for each sequence.  Run the `a` iterator as a `for` loop, while manually using `next(ib)` to get the next value from the `b` sequence.  If we get a `StopIteration` on the `b` sequence, we break the loop and then `for x in ia:` gets the rest of the `a` sequence; after that `for y in ib:` will do nothing because that iterator is already exhausted.  Alternatively, if the first `for x in ia:` loop exhausts the `a` iterator, the second `for x in ia:` does nothing but there could be values left in the `b` sequence and the `for y in ib:` loop collects them.

Comment: `itertools.zip_longest` can handle more than 2 arguments, unlike this code.

Comment: I don't remember what I was thinking in 2012 when I wrote this, but I think I probably just wanted to solve the problem.  I have always felt that if there is a library function that does what you need, you almost never want to write your own instead of using it.  Use the library function.

Answer (score 1):

Single line:

`c = zip(a, b) + [(x,) for x in a[len(b):]] + [(x,) for x in b[len(a):]]`

If you want to reuse this:

```
def mergeUsNicely(a, b):
    def tupleMe(val):
        return (val,)
    return zip(a, b) + map(tupleMe, a[len(b):]) + map(tupleMe, b[len(a):])
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is an extension of the top answer that allows for arbitrary inputs instead of only two.

```
import itertools

sentinel = object()

def zip_longest_no_fill(*args):
    for i in itertools.zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=sentinel):
        yield tuple(x for x in i if x is not sentinel)
```