# How to Sum Two List N-Element

Tags: python, python-2.7

I need to add two lists of numbers. When one list is greater than the other I get the error  "IndexError: list index out of range". The error occurs in line `resultado = v1[i] + v2[i]`, but I don't know how to solve it.

My code is:

```
def suma(A, B):

    if len(A) > len(B):
        v1 = A
        v2 = B
    else:
        v1 = B
        v2 = A
    v3 = []
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(v1)):
        resultado = v1[i] + v2[i]
        v3.append(resultado)
    for j in range(len(v1), len(v2)):
        v3.append(v2[j])
    return v3

vectorA = []
vectorB = []
x = 1
while x !=0:
    print "Ingrese los datos para el primer vector (0 para finalizar)"
    x = input("-->>")
    if x !=0:
        vectorA.append (x)

print "=" * 30
x = 1
while x !=0:
    print "Ingrese los datos para el segundo vector (0 para finalizar)"
    x = input("-->>")
    if x !=0:
        vectorB.append (x)

print "=" * 30
print vectorA
print vectorB
print "=" * 30
print "A) SUMA DE VECTORES"
print "=" * 30

suma(vectorA, vectorB)
print suma
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> A = [1, 2, 3]
>>> B = [10, 11]
>>> [a + b for a, b in itertools.izip_longest(A, B, fillvalue=0)]
[11, 13, 3]
```

- [itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest)

So,

```
def suma(A, B):
    return [a + b for a, b in itertools.izip_longest(A, B, fillvalue=0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You want [`itertools.izip_longest`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11319002/198633)

```
def suma(A, B):
    return map(sum, itertools.izip_longest(A,B, fillvalue=0))
```

Answer (score 2):

What's going to help you more with learning Python at this stage is probably this:

The actual error is caused because you use the **length of the longer list** to iterate over both lists. It is easily resolved by changing

```
for i in range(len(v1)):
```

into

```
for i in range(len(v2)):
```

because, `v2` is the shorter list after the comparison above. You should also replace

```
for j in range(len(v1), len(v2)):        
    v3.append(v2[j])
```

by

```
for j in range(len(v2), len(v1)):        
    v3.append(v1[j])
```

because, after all, `len(v2)` is smaller than `len(v1)`. Finally replace

```
suma(vectorA, vectorB)
print suma
```

by

```
print suma(vectorA, vectorB)
```

to have the result printed. You find the working script below.

```
def suma(A, B):

    if len(A) > len(B):
        v1 = A
        v2 = B
    else:
        v1 = B
        v2 = A
    v3 = []
    i = 0
    for i in range(len(v2)):
        resultado = v1[i] + v2[i]
        v3.append(resultado)
    for j in range(len(v2), len(v1)):
        v3.append(v1[j])
    return v3

vectorA = []
vectorB = []
x = 1
while x !=0:
    print "Ingrese los datos para el primer vector (0 para finalizar)"
    x = input("-->>")
    if x !=0:
        vectorA.append (x)

print "=" * 30
x = 1
while x !=0:
    print "Ingrese los datos para el segundo vector (0 para finalizar)"
    x = input("-->>")
    if x !=0:
        vectorB.append (x)

print "=" * 30
print vectorA
print vectorB
print "=" * 30
print "A) SUMA DE VECTORES"
print "=" * 30

print suma(vectorA, vectorB)
```