# Add two different values to string from different lists

Tags: python, string, list, addition

so i have two different lists of strings; i.e. x and y.

```
len(y) = len(x) - 1
```

i want to add them together in an empty string in the original order so basically the output = x1 + y1 + x2 + y2 + x3

```
x = ['AAA','BBB','CCC']
y = ['abab','bcbcb']

#z = ''
z = 'AAAababBBBbcbcbCCC'
```

how can i create a for-loop to add to this empty string z ?

i usually would do:

```
for p,q in zip(x,y):
```

but since y in smaller than x, it wouldn't add the last value of x

Answer (score 1):

This ought to do it:

```
''.join([item for sublist in zip(x, y+['']) for item in sublist])
```

Answer (score 0):

You want [`itertools.izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest). Also, check out [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318977/zipping-unequal-lists-in-python-in-to-a-list-which-does-not-drop-any-element-fro/11319002#11319002)

```
newStr = ''.join(itertools.chain.from_iterable(
                   itertools.izip_longest(x,y, fillvalue='')
                 ))
```

Comment: More lines! This is too long for a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `roundrobin` [recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) from itertools:

```
from itertools import *
def roundrobin(*iterables):
    "roundrobin('ABC', 'D', 'EF') --> A D E B F C"
    # Recipe credited to George Sakkis
    pending = len(iterables)
    nexts = cycle(iter(it).next for it in iterables)
    while pending:
        try:
            for next in nexts:
                yield next()
        except StopIteration:
            pending -= 1
            nexts = cycle(islice(nexts, pending))
x = ['AAA','BBB','CCC']
y = ['abab','bcbcb']
print "".join(roundrobin(x,y))  
#AAAababBBBbcbcbCCC
```

Or with `itertools.izip_longest` you could do:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> ''.join([''.join(c) for c in izip_longest(x,y,fillvalue = '')])
'AAAababBBBbcbcbCCC'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import izip_longest

x = ['AAA','BBB','CCC']
y = ['abab','bcbcb']

unfinished_z = izip_longest( x,y,fillvalue='' ) # an iterator
unfinished_z = [ ''.join( text ) for text in unfinished_z ] # a list
z = ''.join( unfinished_z ) # the string AAAababBBBbcbcbCCC
```

I prefer more verbosity.