# Create a list from multiple attributes

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Let's say I have a list of dicts or objects, which effectively looks like this:

```py
[
    {'score': 5, 'tally': 6},
    {'score': 1, 'tally': None},
    {'score': None, 'tally': None},
]
```

What would be a Pythonic and concise way of creating a list of all ***‘score’s*** and ***‘tally’s*** that are not None? so the result would the following:

```py
[5, 6, 1 ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this concise solution, using list comprehensions:

```
lst = [{'score': 5, 'tally': 6},
       {'score': 1, 'tally': None},
       {'score': None, 'tally': None}]

[v for m in lst for v in m.values() if v is not None]
=> [6, 5, 1]
```

Comment: This is really nice, thank you! do you know a similar method if the elements in the list aren't dicts? i.e. `score` and `tally` would be attributes on an object.

Comment: It'd be similar, because the attributes in an object are stored in the `__dict__` attribute of the object

Comment: Note that this particular solution won't report if values are 0 or empty strings, etc. Other "falsy" values that aren't None. To find those as well, change the list comprehension to: `[v for m in lst for v in m.values() if v is not None]`

Comment: @brechin you're right, better to play it safe. I updated my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
list(i for i in 
     itertools.chain.from_iterable(
       itertools.izip_longest(
         (d['score'] for d in listOfDicts if d['score'] is not None), 
         (d['tally'] for d in listOfDicts if d['tally'] is not None)
     )) if i is not None)

>>> import itertools
>>> listOfDicts = [
...     {'score': 5, 'tally': 6},
...     {'score': 1, 'tally': None},
...     {'score': None, 'tally': None},
... ]
>>> list(i for i in itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.izip_longest((d['sco
re'] for d in listOfDicts if d['score'] is not None), (d['tally'] for d in listO
fDicts if d['tally'] is not None))) if i is not None)
[5, 6, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I never knew about `izip_longest`. This is similar to how my solution ended up, I just had the feeling I was missing out on a one line list comprehension.

Comment: Yeah, `izip_longest` comes in handy a lot. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11319002/198633) out

Comment: Happy to help! As a side note, it's awesomely refreshing to be addressed by my real name. Usually, everyone just refers to everyone else by their usernames.