# Print different size lists side by side

Tags: python, list, printing

I want to print different size lists side by side.

I'm using

```
In: for n,g in zip(ten_pos,real_pos):
        print (n + "\t\t\t\t\t\t" + g)
```

But If one list has 5 item and the other one has 20, It only prints 5 and 5 and I want 5 and 20.

Is there an easy way to solve this?

Comment: Then use `itertools.izip_longest`. There's probably a dupe for this already. searching . . .

Comment: Also [Zipping unequal lists in python in to a list which does not drop any element from longer list being zipped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318977/zipping-unequal-lists-in-python-in-to-a-list-which-does-not-drop-any-element-fro)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest).

```
import itertools

for a, b in itertools.zip_longest([1,2], [3,4,5]):
    print(a, b)

# outputs
1 3
2 4
None 5
```

You can change the value used to fill with the kwarg `fillvalue`.