# Create dict from two lists, with 1:2 key:value relation

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, zip, list-comprehension

How do I create a dictionary from below lists, `len(keys_list) = 12`, `len(values_list) = 24`.

```
keys_list = ['Al','Bb','Ch','Da','Ev','Fr','Gi','Ht','Ia','Jh','Kd','Ly']
values_list = [i for i in 'VRCGVVRVCGGCCGVRGCVCGCGV']
```

So my output will be `['Al':'VR' or ('V','R') or ['V','R']......]` either way is fine. I tried a few variations of `zip()`; and [reached this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318977/zipping-unequal-lists-in-python-in-to-a-list-which-does-not-drop-any-element-fro) where they used `zip_longest`.

```
import itertools
for i in itertools.zip_longest(keys_list,values_list):
    print (i)
```

I prefer not having to import a module.

Comment: in case the `values list len / keys list len` isn't equal to a round number, what is the logic?

Comment: It's mandatory 1:2 data. 12 to 24 is fixed.

Comment: Will appreciate the reason for down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
keys_list = ['Al','Bb','Ch','Da','Ev','Fr','Gi','Ht','Ia','Jh','Kd','Ly']
values_list = [i for i in 'VRCGVVRVCGGCCGVRGCVCGCGV']

grouped_values = [values_list[i] + values_list[i+1] for i in range(len(values_list) - 1)]
d = {k :v for k,v in zip(keys_list, grouped_values)}
print(d)
```

output

```
{'Al': 'VR', 'Bb': 'RC', 'Ch': 'CG', 'Da': 'GV', 'Ev': 'VV', 'Fr': 'VR', 'Gi': 'RV', 'Ht': 'VC', 'Ia': 'CG', 'Jh': 'GG', 'Kd': 'GC', 'Ly': 'CC'}
```

Comment: I actually needed `range(0, len(values) ,2)` but it's fine thanks. I hadn't thought of treating the string separately. I was thinking of doing it all in one step.

Comment: you can use smth like `grouped_values = [values_list[i:i+2] for i in range(len(values_list) - 1)]` without treating the string separately

Comment: I've got it working with `range(0,len(values),2)` i.e. No overlap of values. That might have not been very clear in the question.