# Using zip_longest on unequal lists but repeat the last entry instead of returning None

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-itertools

There is an existing thread about this
[Zipping unequal lists in python in to a list which does not drop any element from longer list being zipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318977/zipping-unequal-lists-in-python-in-to-a-list-which-does-not-drop-any-element-fro)

But it's not quite I'm after.
Instead of returning `None`, I need it to copy the previous entry on the list.

Is this possible?

```
a = ["bottle","water","sky"]
b = ["red", "blue"]
for i in itertools.izip_longest(a,b):
    print i

#result
# ('bottle', 'red')
# ('water', 'blue')
# ('sky', None) 

# What I want on the third line is
# ('sky', 'blue')
```

Comment: should it return `'blue'` for any subsequent element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.izip_longest` takes an optional `fillvalue` argument that provides the value that is used after the shorter list has been exhausted.  `fillvalue` defaults to `None`, giving the behaviour you show in your question, but you can specify a different value to get the behaviour you want:

```py
    fill = a[-1] if (len(a) < len(b)) else b[-1]
    for i in itertools.izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=fill):
        print i
```

(Obviously if the same list is always the shorter one then choosing the fill character is even easier.)

Answer (score 0):

You can [`chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) the shorter list with a [`repeat`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat) of its last value.  Then using regular [`izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip), the result will be the length of the longer list:

```
from itertools import izip, repeat, chain

def izip_longest_repeating(seq1, seq2):
    if len(seq1) < len(seq2):
        repeating = seq1[-1]
        seq1 = chain(seq1, repeat(repeating))
    else:
        repeating = seq2[-1]
        seq2 = chain(seq2, repeat(repeating))
    return izip(seq1, seq2)   

print(list(izip_longest_repeating(a, b)))
#  [('bottle', 'red'), ('water', 'blue'), ('sky', 'blue')]
```

And here's a version that should work for any iterables:

```
from itertools import izip as zip # Python2 only

def zip_longest_repeating(*iterables):
    iters = [iter(i) for i in iterables]
    sentinel = object() 
    vals = tuple(next(it, sentinel) for it in iters)
    if any(val is sentinel for val in vals):
        return
    yield vals
    while True:
        cache = vals
        vals = tuple(next(it, sentinel) for it in iters)
        if all(val is sentinel for val in vals):
            return
        vals = tuple(old if new is sentinel else new for old, new in zip(cache, vals))
        yield vals

list(zip_longest_repeating(['a'], ['b', 'c'], ['d', 'r', 'f']))
#  [('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'r'), ('a', 'c', 'f')]
```