# How to iterate over multiple lists of different lengths, but repeat the last value of a shorter list until the longest list is done?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, iterator

In my Python 3 script, I am trying to make a combination of three numbers from three different lists based on inputs. If the lists are the same size, there is no issue with `zip`. However, I want to be able to input a single number for a specific list and the script to repeat that number until the longest list is finished. This can be done with `zip_longest`. However, with `fillvalue` it is not possible to have separate fill values for separate lists.

Taking this simple script as an example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

list1=[1]
list2=[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list3=[2]
for l1, l2, l3 in zip_longest(list1, list2, list3):
     print(l1, l2, l3)
```

This is the actual result:

```
# 1    4 2
# None 5 None                                                        
# None 6 None                                                         
# None 7 None
# None 8 None
# None 9 None
```

And this would be the result that I want:

```
# 1 4 2
# 1 5 2                                                        
# 1 6 2                                                         
# 1 7 2
# 1 8 2
# 1 9 2
```

I already managed to do this specific task by manually creating different for loops and asking if a list is a constant or not, but `zip_longest` is so close to exactly what I need that I wonder if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using zip\_longest on unequal lists but avoiding the returned None](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55846806/using-zip-longest-on-unequal-lists-but-avoiding-the-returned-none). The questions and the answers there should be updated to Python 3, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could make use of logical `or` operator to use the last element of the shorter lists:

```
from itertools import zip_longest
list1 = [1]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
list3 = [2]
for l1, l2, l3 in zip_longest(list1, list2, list3):
    print(l1 or list1[-1], l2, l3 or list3[-1])
```

Out:

```
1 a 2
1 b 2
1 c 2
1 d 2
1 e 2
1 f 2
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of `itertools.cycle`, which takes a list and returns a generator, looping through the contents of the list without stop.

```
from itertools import cycle


list1 = [1]
list2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list3 = [2]
for l1, l2, l3 in zip(cycle(list1), list2, cycle(list3)):
     print(l1, l2, l3)
```

Output:

```
1 4 2
1 5 2
1 6 2
1 7 2
1 8 2
1 9 2
```

Note that we used the regular `zip()` instead of `zip_longest()`, otherwise `cycle(list1)` and `cycle(list3)` would keep generating values and we would encounter an infinite loop.

The cool thing with `cycle()` is that your lists will be repeated. For example, the following set of lists will generate a different output from Meyer's solution:

```
list1 = [1, 3]
list2 = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list3 = [2]
```

Output:

```
1 4 2
3 5 2
1 6 2
3 7 2
1 8 2
3 9 2
```

If you just have **one** number you'd like to repeat, you can use `repeat(x)` instead.

```
from itertools import repeat


x, y = 1, 2
list_ = [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

for l1, l2, l3 in zip(repeat(x), list_, repeat(y)):
     print(l1, l2, l3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
zipped = zip(list1 * len(list2), list2, list3 * len(list2))

for item in zipped:
    print(item)  

(1, 'a', 2)
(1, 'b', 2)
(1, 'c', 2)
(1, 'd', 2)
(1, 'e', 2)
(1, 'f', 2)
```